# Dart - How to create a new List<Object2> from an existing List<Object1>

Tags: dart

I have an existing List i.e.

[
  {
    "name": "miller",
    "age": 22,
    "nationality": "Romania",
    "doj": "2018-09-17",
  },
  {
    "name": "sochi",
    "age": 35,
    "nationality": "Poland",
    "doj": "2018-10-11",
  },
  {
    "name": "diana",
    "age": 35,
    "nationality": "Belarus",
    "doj": "2018-12-14",
  }
]

---

and would like to create a new List using the above list (with fewer fields) i.e.

[
  {
    "name": "miller",
    "nationality": "Romania",
  },
  {
    "name": "sochi",
    "nationality": "Poland",
  },
  {
    "name": "diana",
    "nationality": "Belarus",
  }
]

Answer (score 0):

You can map the list and either remove the key that you want to be removed or copy all the keys that you want to keep.

```
  var newList = list.map((e) => e..remove('doj'));
  //or
  var newList = list.map((e) => {'name': e['name'], 'age': e['age'], ...);
```